# Sorting function with output to a separate file

Tags: c++, string, sorting

I need to sort the input text document and write it into another test document. so that lines with an even number of words delete every second word, and lines with an odd number of words remain unchanged. The sorting should be performed as a function, the first pointer to the input of the string and the second pointer to the output.

I did the input and output, tried to do a sorting to begin with without a function, but nothing worked. can you tell me what I did not do the rule?

Example:
Input.txt

> I do not like to go to school or study
> I like to play games

Output.txt

> I not to to or
> I like to play games

```
string in, out;

cin >> in;

cin >> out;

ifstream input(in); 
string str; 
ofstream output(out); 
string st;

while (getline(input, str)) 
{

do
{
    int i = count(str.cbegin(), str.cend(), ' ');
    if (i % 2 == 0)
        st.append(str);
    else
        st.append(" ");
    i++;


} 
while (input);

    output << st << endl;   


}
```

Comment: why are certain words missing from the desired output? what happens to eg "school" ?

Comment: why do you have two nested loops? The state of `input` won't change in the inner one, and it will never stop. Proper intendation would help a lot

Comment: Your question repeatedly mentions "sorting" but nothing about the requirements seems to have anything to do with sorting, just counting and removing words, without changing the order

Comment: Because in the line "I do not like to go to school or study" has an even number of words, every 2 words will removed and will stay "I not to or".
In the line "I like to play games" has an odd number of words and because of this nothing is deleted.

Comment: Your word-counting is pretty unreliable. What if there's a space at the beginning or end of a line, or multiple spaces between words, or someone forgot a space after punctuation, or there is a tab rather than a single space?

Comment: What should we call it if not sorting?

Comment: processing, chunking?

Comment: "performed as a function, the first pointer to the input of the string and the second pointer to the output." what does that mean? Is your teacher asking you to use C style strings and not `std::string`?

Comment: My teacher allows you to use anything, but it must be implemented through the function.

Comment: Have you been taught how to declare a function? You are going to want something like `std::string process(std::string line) { /* stuff here */ }`

Comment: How do I need to change the code to fulfill another condition? (I was given an extra job, and everything I do doesn't work). If a string consists of words of equal length, then put an exclamation mark at the beginning of the string, shifting the original string one character to the right. Example: Input: 1)asdfgh asdfgk kjhgfd hlkjhg 2)jhggk akjhs kjh kjh khkjh Output: 1)!asdfgh asdfgk kjhgfd hlkjhg 2)jhggk akjhs kjh kjh khkjh (1 and 2 are string numbers)

Answer (score 0):

The `std::stringstream` will be your friend.

Read about it [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) and especially for the useful `std::istringstream` [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream).

What can we do with this thing? We can put a string into it and then use the extraction operator `>>` like with any other stream.

So, counting words will become very simple. We read a line from the file as a `std::string` and then put it into a `std::istringstream`, Then we extract dummy words and increase a counter until the reading fails. Then we have the number of words.

Example:

```
// We read one line. Count the number of words
// Put the string in a stringstream to easily extract words
std::istringstream iss(line);

// Counter for words
unsigned int wordCount{};
// Dummy word
std::string tempWord{};

// Do the counting
while (iss >> tempWord) ++wordCount;
```

The stream tries too read until it cannot read any more (the stream is empty) and then sets a failbit. The failure of any stream can be checked with its [bool](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) operator or the [!](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator!)-operator. The `while` loop expects a boolean. And the extraction operation `iss >> tempWord` will return a reference to the stream and then its `bool` operator will be called and used as condition.

OK, understood, we can now count words. Next step is to skip words.

This is similar simple. In case of even number of words in a string, we will read always 2 words in a loop and simply throw the second one away.

Like this

```
std::string usedWord{};

// Read 2 words, ignore the second
while (iss >> usedWord >> tempWord)
    result += (usedWord + ' ');
```

There are of course many other possible ways to solve that, but maybe the below solution can give you an idea.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main() {

    // First read the input filename
    std::cout << "\nPlease enter the path for the input file:\n";
    std::string inputFileName{};
    std::getline(std::cin, inputFileName);

    // next read the output filename
    std::cout << "\nPlease enter the path for the output file:\n";
    std::string outputFileName{};
    std::getline(std::cin, outputFileName);

    // Open now both files. If one file cannot be opened, then no need tocontinue
    // Open input file and check, if it could be opened
    std::ifstream inputFileStream(inputFileName);
    if (inputFileStream) {

        // Input file could be opened without error. 
        // Now open output file and check, if it could be opened
        std::ofstream outputFileStream(outputFileName);
        if (outputFileStream) {

            // Now, both input and output file streams are open
            // Read lines
            std::string line{};
            while (std::getline(inputFileStream, line)) {

                // We read one line. Count the number of words
                // Put the string in a stringstream to easily extract words
                std::istringstream iss(line);

                // Counter for words
                unsigned int wordCount{};
                // Dummy word
                std::string tempWord{};

                // Do the counting
                while (iss >> tempWord) ++wordCount;

                // if the number of words is even then
                if ((wordCount % 2) == 0) {

                    // Rinitialize stringstream
                    iss.clear(), iss.str(line);

                    // Here we store the resulting sentence
                    std::string result{};

                    // Now extract the word that we will keep and the other one that we will throw away
                    std::string usedWord{};

                    // Read 2 words, ignore the second
                    while (iss >> usedWord >> tempWord)
                        result += (usedWord + ' ');

                    // Write result to output
                    outputFileStream << result << '\n';
                }
                else
                    outputFileStream << line << '\n';
            }
        }
        else std::cerr << "\n*** Error: could not open output file '" << outputFileName << "'\n\n";
    }
    else std::cerr << "\n*** Error: could not open input file '" << inputFileName << "'\n\n";
}
```